# How to save an image to the photo gallery using Flutter?

Tags: dart, gallery, flutter, photo

My flutter app uses the [`camera`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) package to take a photo, which I save to the application's data directory (obtained from [`path_provider`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) and the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` function).

How can I save this image file into the phone photo gallery? I've noticed the [`image_picker`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) package allows *reading* from the gallery, but how can I write to it?

Comment: Hey, it's been more than 2 years, did you find any plugin that does what you required(I don't know how to use platform channels)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately flutter doesn't currently expose that functionality. It does seem like a candidate for a plugin though.

If you're motivated enough, you could use [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) to communicate from flutter to native Android (and iOS) code, from which you can get full access the gallery. Bonus points if you make it into a plugin and publish it!

Comment: As far as I know there's no plugin yet for that. I have added this exact case as an example of relatively easy plugin to be implemented, with detailed steps necessary for doing it in my post on https://medium.com/p/contributing-to-flutter-part-2-46092dc4417e.

Comment: Is there any plugin for that now?

Answer (score 20):

https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

this plugin saves images and video to gallery/photos.

You just need to provide it with path to temp file that you got from Camera(or even network url, it also works):

```
GallerySaver.saveVideo(recordedVideo.path);
GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path);
```

**** DEPRICATED
use something else.

Comment: my images have path like  "assets/images/my image.jpg"  its not working... Will you pls tell me the type of recorded.path.  Whats it tyep like File or  binary data or string etc.

Comment: Is it possible to list the media from the gallery after saving?

Comment: Unfortunately this fails on Android 11

Comment: It fails on android 11 due to scoped storage, don't know which package dev will solve this problem first, but waiting for it

Comment: I get wrong timestamp saving GIF to photo album on iOS 14.

Comment: Correction about my above comment... I get wrong timestamp trying to save GIF for both image_gallery_saver and gallery_saver, it was resolved by adding creationTime to PHAssetChangeRequest

Comment: Now we also have a bit more consistent fork of it: https://pub.dev/packages/add_to_gallery

Comment: Both "add_to_gallery" and "gallery_saver" are outdated.

Comment: We should use the [gal package](https://pub.dev/packages/gal) instead in 2023.

Comment: can anybody name "something else"

Answer (score 13):

## 2024

###### *gallery_saver* and its forked packages (like *image_gallery_saver*) are outdated.

###### We should use [gal](https://pub.dev/packages/gal) instead.

```dart
await Gal.putImage(path);
await Gal.putVideo(path);
```

Incidentally, the temporary directory can be obtained without using path_provider, just with this code

```dart
Directory.systemTemp.path;
```

Some people try to save the media in the project's asset folder, so I leave the code for that as well.

```dart
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.jpg');
final file = await File('${Directory.systemTemp.path}${path.replaceAll('assets', '')}').create();
await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
await Gal.putImage(file.path);
```

It works for both Android and iOS. More info can be found in the [example of the gal package](https://github.com/natsuk4ze/gal/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart).
Thank you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The Gal plugin also work on all the mainstream platforms except web. +1

Comment: Can we pass response body to it? like i have a post request for downloading an image n saving it in gallery. Url plus body: {"image": image.jpg}

Answer (score 7):

There is a plugin that supports this.

https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver

I have tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: Also - like gallery_saver - fails on Android 11

Comment: works on android now but fails for iOS :(! Opened an issue on github: https://github.com/CarnegieTechnologies/gallery_saver/issues/93

Comment: actually the saveImage method not works when you specify a name of image. the image name remains in the ios format IMG_XXX. i have open an issue on github but there are many issue remained open for this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I made the plugin. Please try it if you like.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_downloader#-readme-tab-

**update**

I will explain how to use.

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  image_downloader: ^0.9.0
```

After that, specify permission for each devices.

Just write the following and image will be saved.

```
ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url);
```

Comment: I implemented it and ImageDownloader return true, but where is the file located?

Comment: If download image has CreateDate of exif, there is in the date in Photo app(iOS) or download directory(Android).

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me-

```
// https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider
Future<String> getExtStorageOrDownloadsDirPath() async {
  final documentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
     //final extStorageDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
     //return extStorageDir?.path ?? documentsDir.path;
     return '/storage/emulated/0/Download';
  } else {
     final downloadsDir = await getDownloadsDirectory();
     return downloadsDir?.path ?? documentsDir.path;
  }
}
```

Once you get path, you can save like this

```
if (imageBytes != null) {
  XFile xFile = XFile.fromData(imageBytes, mimeType: 'image/png');
  String documentsDirPath = await getExtStorageOrDownloadsDirPath();
  String filePath =
      '$documentsDirPath/${widget.bannerData.creativeTitle?.split(' ').join('-')}.png';
  if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
    // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
    xFile.saveTo(filePath);
    showToastMessage('Saved to $filePath');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for this answer for a while but fortunately, I am able to save files to gallery with this code:

```
ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/example.png');
File file = await File('/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/<your app package>/<App title/folder>/example.png').create(recursive: true);
await MediaStore.saveImage(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
```

This will save your image to the device and your device gallery.

**This only works for Android**

Thanks.

Comment: where is `MediaStore` from?

Answer (score 1):

There is a package which you can use to update the gallery by giving the path of the image or the video. The advantage of this over the other packages is that you can save files even in a sd card. The file will not be saved twice when you try to add media to gallery which are already saved to the device.
This is the link to the package. https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner

```
MediaScanner.loadMedia("Path to the file or directory"); // This will update the gallery
```

**This is Android only**

Answer (score 1):

I had to search a lot, but I found a very useful solution to save the image in the cell phone's photo gallery and get the absolute path to use it the way you want.
For this example I used a result obtained from saving an image in the photo gallery, however it could also work to read other files, obviously making the changes that you see necessary, I hope it will help you
[uri_to_file](https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file)
[image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver)

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:uri_to_file/uri_to_file.dart';

Future<File> saveImage(File image, String identifier) async {
try {
    var result = await 
    ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image.readAsBytesSync(),
     quality: 60, name: identifier + 
    "-${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}");
    print(result);
    File file = await toFile(Uri.parse(result['filePath']));
    print(file);
    return file;
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
    return new File('assets/img/default-img.jpg');
  }
}
// example
saveImage(File("path/image/img223.jpg"),"img-test");
// or
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, I made it worked by specifying path to "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/YOUR_FOLDER/YOUR_FILE_NAME" then it will be saved outside of support package directory then image appears in Gallery.
You can use any image saver plugin just provide that hardcoded path.